# How Power BI apps handle modification?

Tags: powerbi

I would like to understand how power BI Apps is handling modification for users

Actually my reports are shared in apps with many other users and need to make sure that if i modify any slicer for example : zooming on a specific area , does it impact other user's view ?

Thanks in advance! I really appreciate you time and effort

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking, but if it's about viewing published reports, then I think the answer is it doesn't impact other users.

Comment: Should be easy to confirm - open a report in multiple tabs and modify in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as when you pin the 'whole' report into a dashboard. You will change the view (filtering, zooming, etc) in the report but the dashboard will be displayed in the original (unfiltered, unzoomed) view.

Comment: Thank you Steve for your help!